# Merging 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge the following 2 dataframes.

df.head():

```
        x     y     z   w
0  0.0056    11   824  51
1  0.0056   138   546  16
2  0.0056   328  1264  40
3  0.0056  1212   553  91
4  0.0056  1839   388  48
```

df1.head():

```
           x      y     z
0  5539.0567  12243    27
1  5873.2923  14474  1540
2  3975.9776  11353   699
3  1508.5975   8250   628
4    66.7913  11812   538
```

using the following command:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df, how='left',left_on=(['x','y','z']),right_index=True)
```

and the following error crops up:

> ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"

In total df has 11458060 rows and df1 has 2528243 rows

I don't really know what this means. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If you indicate left_on = something in your merge, you also have to indicate right_on. This is only useful when the columns in your two dataframes don't have the same names. Otherwise just use on = something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on columns `x`, `y` and `z`:

```
print df1.merge(df, how='left', on=['x','y','z'])
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).

Parameter *on* in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

> *on*: Columns (names) to join on. Must be found in both the left and right DataFrame objects. If not passed and left_index and right_index are False, the intersection of the columns in the DataFrames will be inferred to be the join keys